# Testing text contrast in react-native

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

Not actually sure, it is should be done with jest.
But how to ensure, that found text on the screen is visible?
There are my short files for example:
(setted color of text to be same as bg, but it passes)[image]

in text format to you, if you want copy/paste

```
export default () => (
  <SafeAreaView style={ style.container }>
    <Text style={ style.text }>loading..</Text>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

,

```
test('In Loading screen, there is "loading" visible label', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <Loading />
  )

  getByText(/loading/) // exact 1 (not 0, not >)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test most likely passes because technically the text is on the page and is detectable by the tool. But as the background color is the same as the foreground (text) color, it will not be visible on the page by humans - the color contrast will be 1:1 while the lowest is 3:1 for large or bold text and UI and 4.5:1 for regular text.

- For **automated testing**, the [Jest-aXe](https://github.com/nickcolley/jest-axe#testing-react-with-react-testing-library) could be handy, plus, it is also compatible with React Testing Library.
- For **manual testing** of the contrast, tools like [Colour Contrast Analyser](https://github.com/ThePacielloGroup/CCAe) could be used.